# How Return all when Using Take in Linq statement in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Take property that if I pass a number I want to show for example top (4) and when the Take is 0 I want to return all, this is my code that is returning Top 4 when I pass Take = 4 but when Take is 0 I dont know how to return all.

```
  var Notes = await zigzyDbContext.RealEstateAgentNotes
            .Include(i => i.RealEstateAgent)
            .Where(w => w.RealEstateAgent.Guid == request.RealEstateAgentGuid)
            .Join(zigzyDbContext.SupportUsers,
                j => j.CreatedById,
                j => j.Id,
                (j, k) => new
                {
                    RealEstateAgentNote = j,
                    Support = k
                })
            .Where(w => w.Support != null)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.RealEstateAgentNote.CreatedDate)
            .Take(request.Take)
            .ToListAsync();
```

and this is the request property:

```cs
            public Guid RealEstateAgentGuid { get; set; }
            public int Take { get; set; }
```

Comment: it just returns an IEnumerable with 0 items

Comment: @MohsenZahedi - Yes but I need some How return All too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the ternary operator inside the Take function

```
 var Notes = await zigzyDbContext.RealEstateAgentNotes
            .Include(i => i.RealEstateAgent)
            .Where(w => w.RealEstateAgent.Guid == request.RealEstateAgentGuid)
            .Join(zigzyDbContext.SupportUsers,
                j => j.CreatedById,
                j => j.Id,
                (j, k) => new
                {
                    RealEstateAgentNote = j,
                    Support = k
                })
            .Where(w => w.Support != null)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.RealEstateAgentNote.CreatedDate)
            .Take(request.Take > 0 ? request.Take:Int32.MaxValue)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build your queryable conditionally.

```cs
var query = zigzyDbContext.RealEstateAgentNotes
            .Include(i => i.RealEstateAgent)
              .Where(w => w.RealEstateAgent.Guid == request.RealEstateAgentGuid)
            .Join(zigzyDbContext.SupportUsers,
                j => j.CreatedById,
                j => j.Id,
                (j, k) => new
                {
                    RealEstateAgentNote = j,
                    Support = k
                })
            .Where(w => w.Support != null)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.RealEstateAgentNote.CreatedDate);

if (request.Take > 0)
{
    query = query.Take(request.Take)
}

var notes = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: it giving error that cannot convert as query does not have type.

Comment: @alma I edited it, you need to put the "await" later.

Answer (score -1):

Just leave out "take" and the toListAsync() will return all.  Btw, Linqpad is a great tool for playing with Linq constructs (https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: I need to have both - Take and return All.

Comment: As mentioned by ESG you need to only add take when you want to limit the results. Otherwise, leave it off.